# I am trying to generate a permutation of polynomial with order m

Tags: random-number-generator

> [image: unknown source]

Suppose m = 5 and N = 64. How do I choose the coefficients such that the polynomial is a permutation of nos from 0 to 63.?

Comment: Please, could you tell us from where you picked this image? It is strange because it seems the authors are using *order* in lieu of *degree*...

Comment: @Vitor: perhaps they're not using the term *degree* because they don't want to assert the constraint that $a_m \ne 0$

Comment: @poncho I see... Anyway, maybe this question is off-topic here and should be moved to math exchange. What do you think?

Comment: Please cite the source from which you are quoting text.

Comment: @Vitor: that makes a lot of sense to me; I don't see any immediate connection with cryptography

Comment: I have an encryption software named PERMUTATIONPOLYNORMIALS which contains functions dealing with their generations on computer. See s13.zetaboards.com/Crypto/topic/7340875/1/

Comment: @Arya ***Which paper is this from? What is the source of that image?***

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is on topic. In general this is a math question and there are various permutation polynomial families, such as Dickson polynomials, see Wikipedia under "permutation polynomials".

In the case $N=2^m$ (which seems to be the one you are interested in, though the term "order" instead of "degree" is problematic) there is a nice paper discussing such polynomials, by Ron Rivest entitled "Permutation polynomials modulo $2^w$ $w\geq 1.$ I state the main result.

$P(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_d x^d$ over the integers modulo $2^w$ is a permutation polynomial if and only if $a_1$ is odd, $a_2+a_4+a_6+\cdots$ is even, and $a_3+a_5+a_7+\cdots$ is even.

See the paper for more related results, e.g., on polynomials generating latin squares mod $2^w$, just google "Rivest permutation polynomial".